# Make a Mac sound an alarm when it can't ping a server?

Tags: macos, mac, bash

Is there a way I can make a Mac Mini sound an audible alarm when it's not connected to the Internet?

I'm quite handy with bash, so if bash is the answer I could create a couple of commands - one to turn it on, one to turn it off - and create some desktop icons for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following loop will send a single ICMP ECHO request (ping) to your ISP and then sleep for a second.  If a reply isn't received within two seconds, it will play the file alarm.wav.

```
YOUR_ISP=1.2.3.4
while :
do
  ping  -t 2 -o -c 1 $YOUR_ISP || open alarm.wav
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: for more fun, replace "open alarm.wav" with "say ping failed"

Comment: will the test continue to run each second? will alarm.wav keep playing? will it re-open the wav every second? will it stop playing once connection has returned?

Comment: The test will continue.  The alarm will play continuously as long as the connection is down and will stop once the connection has returned.

Answer (score 3):

The following will ping once and tell iTunes to start playing if the ping failed.

```
ping -c 1 128.111.1.1 ||
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes"' -e "play" -e "end tell"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `ping -A 1.1.1.1` and it will blip on every failed request.

lowercase `a` will ping for every successful request, instead (`ping -a 1.1.1.1`)

```
> man ping
...
     -A      Audible.  Output a bell (ASCII 0x07) character when no packet is received before the next packet is
             transmitted.  To cater for round-trip times that are longer than the interval between
             transmissions, further missing packets cause a bell only if the maximum number of unreceived
             packets has increased.
```

```
 -a      Audible.  Include a bell (ASCII 0x07) character in the output when any packet is received.  This
         option is ignored if other format options are present.
```